# In Python 3.5, how can I specify a function as a type hint?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, static-typing

What is the appropriate type hint to specify that a variable should be a function (the equivalent of a delegate, `Func<T>` or `Action` in C#)?

Is it also possible to specify the function argument types in a generic fashion as well (for example `Func<int, int>`)?

I cannot find any relevant details in the documentation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), you can use Callable, imported from typing.

You can view more details in [PEP 0484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#callable).